# How to select records on the right table which have only one record inthe related left table (1:n) using ActiveRecord in Yii framework 2?

Tags: php, yii2

Below is my 1:n relational database.

```
my_left_table 
left_id     name 
1            A
2            B
3            C

my_right_tabe
right_id     thing     left_id_fk
1           D          1
2           E          1
3           F          2 
4           G          3
5           H          3
6           I          3
```

I would like to have the following result.

```
 my_left_table 
left_id     name 
2            B
```

Because `left_id = 2` has only one related record in the `my_right_tabe`. How to use the ActiveRecord in Yii framework 2? Using scope is more desirable if possible, otherwise any working solution is also great. Thanks you guys!

Comment: Using pure sql, this is a simple and regularly discussed task.

Comment: I know pure sql will be simple, but I would like to utilize what ActiveRecord offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `groupBy` together with `having`. Try this:

```
$result = MyLeftTable::find()->joinWith('myRightTable rt')->groupBy('rt.right_id')->having(['count(rt.right_id)' => 1]);
```

Assuming that your `MyLeftTable` model has the has-many relationship `getMyRightTable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend  your model class for left_table  adding a proper get function   (eg: getRight)

```
 class Customer extends ActiveRecord
{
  // ...

  public function getRight()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(MyRightTableModel::className(), ['left_id_fk' => 'left_id']);
  }
}
```

then when you access  to each left model

```
  $leftModel = MyLeftModel::findOne(123);
```

you have  rightModels is an array of rightModels objects

```
  $rightModels = $leftModel->right;
```

see thi guide for som tips  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. I would like to select all records in the left table where each record has only one related record in the right table. E.g. using MyLeftModel->find()->all().

Comment: then seems to me that the question of gmc is what you need ... otherwise you can use a findBySql .. using the  raw sqlcode you need based on the model you want retrive ..  so you get the active record  related ..